# No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.SPRING.KAFKA.PROPERTIES.SECURITY.PROTOCOL

Tags: spring, maven, apache-kafka, java-11, azure-eventhub

```
maven
springframework - 2.7.15
java - 11
spring-kafka - 2.8.11
```

```
properties
spring.kafka.bootstrap.servers=mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=XXXXXX;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXX";
```

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapAddress;
@Value("${spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config")
private String saslJaasConfig;
@Value("spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol")
private String securityProtocol;
@Value("spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism")
private String saslMechanism;
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
Map<String, Object> configPropos = new HashMap<>();
configPropos.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
configPropos.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
configPropos.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
configPropos.put("security.protocol", securityProtocol);
configPropos.put("sasl.mechanism", saslMechanism);
configPropos.put("sasl.jaas.config", saslJaasConfig);
//        configPropos.put("org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.SPRING.KAFKA.PROPERTIES.SECURITY.PROTOCOL", "SASL_SSL");

return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configPropos);
}
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
}
```

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class KafkaProducerCreator {

private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
private final static String topicName = "topicoTeste";

public KafkaProducerCreator(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate){
this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}

public void sendMessageToTopic(String message){
kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
}
}
```

Ao executar o método a seguir:

```
try {
String conteudo = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(command);
kafkaProducerCreator.sendMessageToTopic(conteudo);
} catch (Exception e) {
log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Ocorre o erro a seguir:

```
2023-10-27 15:04:20.113  INFO 18172 --- [io-50640-exec-6] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser                  : App info kafka.producer for producer-1 unregistered
2023-10-27 15:04:20.114 ERROR 18172 --- [io-50640-exec-6] c.b.s.d.r.d.ApplicationCoreImpl          : Failed to construct kafka producer

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.SPRING.KAFKA.PROPERTIES.SECURITY.PROTOCOL
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240) ~[?:?]
```

Alguém saberia qual o problema ocorre ao conectar um projeto spring com o kafka do eventhubs do AKS?!

Revisei as configurações da propriedade e ate mesmo defini o valor SASL_SSL na propriedade org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.SPRING.KAFKA.PROPERTIES.SECURITY.PROTOCOL da classe ConfigKafkaProducer.